# Delete UITableViewCell w/o Delete button?

Tags: iphone, sdk

I need to be able to swipe on a cell and instead of showing the red "Delete" button, show an AlertView asking if the user really wants to delete.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can add gestureRecognizer to your cell

```
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer =[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(removeCell:)];
    recognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [recognizer release];
```

and then in removeCell method

```
  - (void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
 {
     UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[recognizer view];
     NSIndexPath* pathOfTheCell = [viewListTable indexPathForCell:cell]; 
     NSInteger rowOfTheCell = [pathOfTheCell row];
     NSInteger sectionOftheCell = [pathOfTheCell section];  

     UIAlertView *confirmationAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Confirm" message:@"Are you sure you want to Delete this list?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Delete", nil];
     [confirmationAlert show];
     confirmationAlert.delegate = self;
     [confirmationAlert release];
 }
```

Comment: I need to be able to access the indexPath of the cell.

Comment: chk now, it will give you indexpath of cell

Comment: Thank you, yaar, I will try tomorrow. Shukraan!

Answer (score 0):

Do Like this,

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    

 UIAlertView *Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Are you sure to commit with its action" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:CKString(@"NO") otherButtonTitles:CKString(@"YES"),nil];
    [Alert show];
    Alert.tag=indexPath.row+1;
    Alert.delegate=self;
    [Alert release];

    return UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


}
```

In AlertView Delegate

```
-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

        int indexPathRow=alertView.tag-1;
        if(buttonIndex==1)
        {
            //// Yes condition
        } else {
           ///// No condition
        }

}
```

Comment: Still have same problem, how do I access indexPath to delete the rows in the alertView delegate?

Comment: See everyone told me to add GestureRecognizer.

Answer (score 0):

Add `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to `Cell`

```
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gesture;
    gesture = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)] autorelease];
    gesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:gesture];

    gesture = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)] autorelease];
    gesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

And inside selector method prompt for Confirm Delete

```
- (void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{    

    //Use recognizer.direction to check left/right swipe if needed
    //Prompt Alert

    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:tableView];
    NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
    UITableViewCell *swipedCell  = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];
}
```

Comment: I need to be able to access the indexPath of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

In Alertview delegate

```
if (alertView.tag == index)
{
if (buttonIndex == 1)
{
  [yourArray removeObjectAtIndex:alertView.tag-1];
  [yourTable reloadData];
}
}
```